# Audio sprite plays only certain parts?

Tags: javascript, html

I have loaded an audio file into an object's property. I use it as sprite where each section has a start time and end time specified. Then I use this code to play that particular part of the audio file:

```
speak: function(str) {
        this.vo.currentTime = 0;
        var curr = {};

        curr = this.sprite[str];
        this.vo.currentTime = curr[0];
        this.vo.volume = _data.vol[1];
        this.vo.play();

        var onTimeUpdate = function() {
            if (this.currentTime >= curr[1]) {
                this.pause();
                this.load();
                this.currentTime = 0;
            }
        };

        this.vo.addEventListener('timeupdate', onTimeUpdate, false);
    }
```

the "vo" is the audio file loaded as `vo = new Audio('..file..')`
The "str" is the name of the property which contains the start and end time of that part. example: if i pass `aud.speak('hello');` then it plays the part of the sprite where it says "hello".

**The problem: Once a part is played, most of the other parts won't play after that.** I have tried everything almost. that's why you see `.load(), .pause(), .currentTime = 0;` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by reloading the audio file everytime the `speak()` method is called. Since the file is hosted locally, it is not a problem to reload it again, but it probably won't be the best solution for someone using hosted content.

```
this.vo = new Audio('..file..');
```

I added this line at the start of `speak()` method.